# Infopath 2010 drop down field to populate document library field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, infopath

I have Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise and Infopath 2010.

I have a complex form created in Infopath with over 200 fields and numerous conditions. The form when submitted kicks off various workflows. The form is simply stored in a document library which can control the workflow status and assign it to certain roles for review and approval etc..

I have taken over this project from a previous coworker who is no longer with my company so I am not sure of how he connected the "name" and "comments" to display in the document library item properties fields. I have added a dropdown combo box to the infopath form which I need to link to the document library so users can ultimately search/ sort submitted items using the combobox fields.

I have tried adding data connections but it does not populate my selected items in the drop down on Sharepoint.
Below you will see an example of the edit properties of the submitted form where I want the "Departments" drop down to be populated with the Infopath form's selected "Departments" drop down. Name and Comments History is currently synced.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Trying to search my memory from when I worked with InfoPath, there are 4 places I would say you might want to check: The InfoPath form's data connections (I'd check here first since this should be the standard way to send the field data to the SP doc library), The workflows that get kicked off, the rules on the InfoPath form fields, and finally if there is any custom JS in a CEWP on the doc library itself. It's possible any of those may be pulling the data and writing it to the library item.

Comment: Have you found any solution.I have the same requirement. Could you tell me how did you resolve it

Comment: Hi Sai, no, still working on resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the fields were promoted to columns. In the InfoPath form, go to Form Options and click on the Property Promotion category. See if the 2 fields you mentioned are listed. If so, simply click Add to add your desired column(s) and click OK, then publish the form.

Comment: Thanks PirateEric, looked there and found the fields and added my new drop down field name. I published it and then submitted a test form. The dropdown selection is still not populating in sharepoint. They are both titled the same 'Department'. Are there any additional steps I need to take to make sure the data within my infopath combobox is transferred over to the sharepoint columns?